# Como funciona a indexação automática de um blog?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

Estou criando um site de notícias, e vejo sites como G1 e o Tecmundo usando uma indexação automática para suas notícias, como isso funciona?
Bem, vou explicar melhor: Eu tenho um arquivo que lê as notícias através de um SELECT usando como referência um id (example.com/reader?id=1), já os sites de notícias mais famosos utilizam isso de forma diferente (example.com/esta-e-uma-noticia-de-exemplo). Como isso funciona? Como posso implementar?

Comment: Acho que o nome é [_slug_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335215/what-is-a-slug)

Comment: Esse recurso é chamado de "URL amigável" e para que funcione o servidor deve ser configurado. No caso dos servidores Apache, a configuração é feita no arquivo `.htaccess`, já nos servidores IIS, a configuração é feita no `web.config`. Veja mais aqui: [Aprendendo URLs amigáveis](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-urls-amigaveis)